# Multiple dois into the same query for scopus search

Tags: search, scopus

In scopus search it is possible to use the doi:

```
DOI(103/4fu49)
```

How is it possible to include multiple dois into the same query?

Answer (score 5):

You have to go to "Advanced Search" in Scopus. You can search for multiple DOIs like this:

> DOI("doi1") OR ("doi2") OR...

Although its an old question, maybe helps someone.